# Java Scanner for 2 threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to build a program where I want to input (using Scanner) few numbers like 5,3,6,65,33,1,24,12 and then print them using 2 threads. First thread will print lower to higher, Second thread will print higher to lower. I will write here pseudocode and then I will explain my problem.

```
class tThread() extends Thread
{
  tThread(String name)
 {
   super(name);
   start();
 }

 public void run()
 {
   // here is Scanner

   //open try block
   if(getName().equals("Thread #1"))
  {
    //here I write data who print lower to higher 
  }
   else if(getName().equals("Thread #2"))
  {
    //here I write data who print higher to lower
  }
}


public class ThreadDemo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    tThread t1 = new tThread("Thread #1");
    tThread t2 = new tThread("Thread #2");
  }
```

Because Scanner is inside run() method, and because I have 2 threads in main(),
when I run this project, I need to data input 2 times. How can I put Scanner only in main to request only once for input, and then send input to those 2 threads? I know that maybe I need to sync those 2 threads, but this is not a problem, I will do it later. All I want to know is how to solve this issue with Scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a static variable in your class, and synchronized it.

scan and put the datas in it.

before launching your threads.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing stopping you from adding the input to a list `List<String>` in main through Scanner and then add a second parameter to the constructor of

```
tThread(String name, List<String> input){
   super(name);
   this.inputList = input;
}
```

Where inputList is private and final and NOT static.

That being said there are a number of issues with your code. I know that it is pseudocode but to make sure. Do not start a thread in its constructor. (see [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0618/index.html) for in-depth explanation).

Prefer implementing `Runnable` than extending `Thread` and prefer threadPools instead of spawning threads (in production at least).

Also do not use the name as tag rather create different implementation of runnables because this way if you add a third method you will need to add yet another if else.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I tried to follow your example but I lost myself in code later. I tried then what @guillaume girod-vitouchkina said and worked. I also want to thank you for telling me about issues in code, because I didn't knew that. My teacher gave us in class examples like that and I tought they are kind of "professional way".

Comment: no problem. In this particular case what was suggested works perfectly, however in big scenarios if you have a change to SAFELY avoid synchronization you should try it. About your teacher's suggestions I have not seen them so I cannot say anything but take heed of the advice about starting threads in constructors.